# Cannot run app on iOS device after upgrading to React Native 0.37

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I upgraded to React Native v0.37. The iOS Simulator works fine but when trying to run the app on a device I get the error:

```
[fatal][tid:main] No script URL provided. Make sure the packager is running or you have embedded a JS bundle in your application bundle.unsanitizedScriptURLString:((null))
```

Does anyone have a clue why?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is working fine now. hard to tell what I've done, maybe running a clean and restarting the server. Hard to tell but it's running ok now.

Comment: Any luck so far? I am experiencing the same issue. Running react-native 0.35.0.

Comment: Nope, sorry, no more info, except cleaning the project in xcode, and restarting the server.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are allowing localhost in you Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I had the issue again after upgrading to React Native 0.38.

I ran "react-native bundle --dev false --assets-dest ./ios --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle" to do the bundling in a clean way and figured out that there was an error caused by a Babel plugin configuration issue. After cleaning my .babelrc file, the packaging is working perfectly well. It then generates the main.jsbundle, and you have to add it to the project in xcode. After that compilation runs fine.